# Internet running slow. Could someone clarify this traceroute output?

Tags: linux, traceroute

So my internet is running slow. I'm on fedora Linux and I think know what im doing (meaning I'm sure it's not any apps or etc.). But this seems to be some provider related thing (Cox). Looking a this traceroute output -> am I correct to presume that ther is some issue with cox internal network that make the hop from my router to Cox server (10.4.8.1) super slow?

```
[stan@localhost ~] $ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.10.1)  0.231 ms  0.429 ms  0.508 ms
 2  10.4.8.1 (10.4.8.1)  919.504 ms  919.536 ms  919.527 ms
 3  ip98-190-163-106.ri.ri.cox.net (98.190.163.106)  919.753 ms  919.798 ms  920.599 ms
 4  ip98-190-33-34.ri.ri.cox.net (98.190.33.34)  923.464 ms  923.388 ms  923.327 ms
 5  ip98-190-33-34.ri.ri.cox.net (98.190.33.34)  923.134 ms  923.183 ms  923.133 ms
 6  nyrkbprj01-ae3.0.rd.ny.cox.net (68.1.5.157)  929.220 ms  953.393 ms  1056.273 ms
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)  980.248 ms  760.047 ms  795.838 ms
[stan@localhost ~] $
```

EDIT:
Nvm. I know it's been awhile - but I figures it out. I actually have apache server hooked up to HDD movies drive. My brother was streaming HD movies from there which is why it clogged all traffic.

Comment: This only means that the intermediate hops doesn't want to reply to `traceroute`. As a probably irrelevant tip, `mtr` ([My Traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software))) provides more info than `traceroute` and is better for diagnosing what your ISP/Firewall is doing. It's also more interactive. Basically it's a program that `ping`s the traceroute midpoints continuously.

Comment: I think telephoning your ISP is a nice solution though.

Comment: also, your link is flooded.  919ms in one hop....i presume that "gateway" is your machine and "10.4.8.1" is the ISP's side of the pppoe or whatever link?

Comment: @cas yeah exactl. 10.4.8.1 is ISP.  What does it mean my link is flooded?

Comment: it means you have an enormous amount of traffic crossing the link,  more than it can cope with.  ping times like that for a few seconds or minutes are no problem, but if it continues for hours, it could mean your gateway box is being attacked.  or someone is downloading torrents or watching videos. or you have too many users using too small a pipe.  too many possibilities to list them all.  try running `tcpdump` or `wireshark` on your external network interface (e.g. ppp0) and see if you can interpret what's going on.

Comment: @cas thanks. um well my gf is watching netflix -> could that be it? (if so -Meliisa- no more netflix)

Comment: could be.   upgrading your internet connection may be a wiser move for household happiness.

Comment: Use `tracepath` (`sudo apt-get install iputils-tracepath;man tracepath`) to check your MTU. If your connection passes through DSL, it should be 1492, I think, If your MTU is too big, then the router between the bigMTU and smallMTU regions will have to fragment each packet, doubling the packet count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Nvm. I know it's been awhile - but I figured it out. I actually have apache server serving movies from HDD drive. My friend was streaming HD movies from there which is why it clogged all traffic.